# How do I return a list of all paths from top left to bottom right in 2D matrix in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

Given a matrix (I present it as a list of lists), how do I return a list of all paths from top left to bottom right of the matrix in Python? I looked at 
[this link](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/print-all-paths-from-top-left-to-bottom-right-in-two-dimensional-array/) and tried to translate into python. But it can only print out the paths.

How to store the paths as a list of list? Below is an example of a 3X3 matrix with appropriate numbers:

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
  r = []
  for j in range(3):
    r.append(i+1)
  a.append(r)
```

Thus I will get matrix

1 1 1

2 2 2

3 3 3

My translated code in python 2.7

```
def printall(currentRow, currentColumn, nums):

    if ( currentRow == len(a) - 1):

        for i in range(currentColumn, len(a[0])):
            nums.append(a[currentRow][i])
        print nums
        return 

    if (currentColumn == len(a[0]) - 1):

        for i in range(currentRow, len(a)):
            nums.append(a[i][currentColumn])
        print nums
        return 

    nums.append(a[currentRow][currentColumn])
    printall(currentRow+1, currentColumn, nums)
    printall(currentRow, currentColumn+1, nums)

print(printall(0,0,[]))
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code that mimics the code in the link?

Comment: I just pasted my code. This code is only printing out the paths and the paths are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is the use of the nums list to hold the paths. You are passing a reference to the same list in each case, which messes up the results when you make recursive calls. Replace those with

```
printall(currentRow+1, currentColumn, nums[:])
printall(currentRow, currentColumn+1, nums[:])
```

Doing this will make a copy of the list each time.

Then finally, to test it out just use `printall(0,0,[])`, you don't need the print in front because you are doing all the printing inside the function.

Comment: Makes sense! How  do you write another function to change the results of printall function as a list of lists (paths)?

Comment: Create another list called something like "all_paths" as a global variable, and where it says "print nums", instead add nums to all_paths.

Comment: If the answer above worked for you please accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi Jeff, if I only want to find the paths that add up to a sum only: for example a list of summed numbers = [12, 8]  for the 3X3 matrix above, where each summed number = sum of all numbers in the path. How will I modify the recursive function then?

Comment: The site's admins generally don't like a continued Q&A in the comments on an answer, as it makes the site disorganized. I would suggest you keep trying and then if you get stuck ask a new question.